# How to print only certain cells of my table in Django templates?

Tags: django, templates, html-table

I am developing an app in Django.

I have on my template (**code 0**):

```
{% for row in query_result %}

    <tr>
    {% for cell in row %}

        <td>{{ cell }}</td>

    {% endfor %} 
    </tr>

{% endfor %}
```

Let's suppose I want my template to print only the first and the third column of my matrix, how can I indicate to my template a specific cell?

I tryed with

```
{% for row in query_result %}

    <tr>


        <td >{{ cell[0] }}</td>
        <td >{{ cell[2] }}</td>


    </tr>

{% endfor %}
```

but it does not work.

EDIT:

As suggested, I tryed with (**code 2**):

```
{% for row in query_result %}

    <tr>


        <td >{{ cell.0 }}</td>
        <td >{{ cell.2 }}</td>


    </tr>

{% endfor %}
```

But this somehow erases the content of my cells, see here below.

results of **Code 0**:

[image]

results of **code 2**:

[image]

Comment: `{{ cell.0 }}` and `{{ cell.2 }}`, but why do you have these cells in the first place?

Comment: you can do this in views.py

Comment: @sandeep: what is the difference between code 1 and code 2.

Comment: @Tms91: what exactly is the type of the `row`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem query_result is a list of tuples, so, row is a tuple

Comment: @Tms91: the reason this did not work was that you iterated over a `row`, but used `cell` in `cell[2]`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem you are right! Type it as answer and I wll flag it as correct. thanks!

Comment: @Tms91: it is already in the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59877429/67579

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain an item at an index in Django's template engine by fetching it as you would fetch an attribute, so:

```
{% for row in query_result %}
    <tr>
        <td >{{ row.0 }}</td>
        <td >{{ row.2 }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

That being said, I strongly advise to try to fix the problem *upstream*: instead of rendering a subset, take a look what you can do to limit the "columns" in `query_result`.

or you can unpack the elements and put the second item in a "throwaway" variable:

```
{% for cell0, __, cell2 in query_result %}
    <tr>
        <td >{{ cell0 }}</td>
        <td >{{ cell2 }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use looks like `{{ cell.0 }}` this. The Django docs explain in the section [variables and lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#variables-and-lookups).

So you would do something like:

```
{% for row in query_result %}
    <tr>
        <td >{{ cell.0 }}</td>
        <td >{{ cell.2 }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: this somehow erases the content of my cells. see the edit (1) in the answer

Comment: it should be row.0 instead of cell.0